mongodb return a list of objects from a collection that aren't in any sub documents of another collection
In this mongo playground I have two collections: vulns and tracker.
I would like a query that can return a list of vulns that do not appear in tracker against a specific customerId.
Essentially I'd like to create a list of advisoryIds as an array for the $nin expression - Mongo Playground.
This query is equivalent to what should be returned:
db.vulns.find({
  "advisoryId": {
    $nin: [
      "44444",
      "55555"
    ]
  }
})

And I was able to get those values using a projection:
db.tracker.find({
  "customerId": "12345"
},
{
  "advisory.advisoryId": 1,
  _id: 0
})

I just need to find a way to combine those queries.

When you say "vulns that do not appear in tracker against a specific customerId." - do you want to check against (A) a specific customerId in the query or (B) just return all vulns that don't appear for some csutomers? Or (C) Or do you want to check which vulns don't appear in any trackers?

Okay, using your example where you find() the advisories for "customerId": "12345" and then lookup the one's which are missing for that customerId - presumably that's how you want the combination to occur.
This pipeline will lookup up each advisoryId from vulns in the trackers collection and additionally match on the customerId. Whenever the lookup presents no results ie an empty array, those are the missing advisories:
db.vulns.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "tracker",
      let: {
        advId: "$advisoryId",
        // put the customerId here
        custId: "12345"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                { $eq: ["$customerId", "$$custId"] },
                { $eq: ["$advisory.advisoryId", "$$advId"] }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "found_trackers"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "found_trackers": []
    }
  },
  { $unset: "found_trackers" }
])

Mongo Playground

That totally seems to work. It's scaring me off a bit though  -- might have to rethink the decision to use mongo instead of SQL. Looking at that makes me think maybe the data is architected incorrectly...

@Darren That really depends on your use-case. In SQL that would be SELECT * FROM vulns LEFT JOIN tracker ON vulns.advisoryId = tracker.advisoryId AND tracker.customerId = '12345' WHERE tracker.advisoryId IS NULL - so if you didn't know SQL already, that query would look scary too. Smaller than the pipeline yes but NoSQL can do other aggregations which are much harder in SQL. Each has their advantages and disadvantages in different scenarios.

Here's another way to do it by first "$match"ing in the tracker collection, collecting the unique advisory.advisoryIds into an array, and then "$lookup" the non-matching docs in vulns.
Comments are in the pipeline.
db.tracker.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      // specific customerId
      "customerId": "12345"
    }
  },
  {
    // make array of all unique advisory.advisoryId's
    // for the specific customerId
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "notAdvIds": {
        "$addToSet": "$advisory.advisoryId"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // go find the vulns not in the array
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "vulns",
      "let": {
        "notAdvIds": "$notAdvIds"
      },
      "as": "vulns",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$not": {"$in": ["$advisoryId", "$$notAdvIds"]}
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  // just output formatting from here
  {
    // create separate doc for each vuln
    "$unwind": "$vulns"
  },
  {
    // make doc just the vuln
    "$replaceWith": "$vulns"
  }
])

Try it on mongoplayground.net.
